# What value is returned by jquery's :checked?

Tags: jquery, checked

What value will the variable `checked` have if the checkbox is checked? What is its value if the checkbox is unchecked?

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="my_id" />
```

jQuery:

```
var checked = $('input#my_id').is(':checked');
```

Comment: That just what I used. I'm kind of a newbie. Is there a better way to determine if a checkbox is checked? I need to send this value via ajax to my PHP script. I thought the value was set to `true` or `false`, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: What does appear to be the case?

Comment: Get some more ideas at: http://jsfiddle.net/webwarrior/NJwv4/9/

Comment: @ShaunOReilly or, a variation http://jsfiddle.net/NJwv4/30/ :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [jQuery documentation for `is`](http://docs.jquery.com/Is).

> Checks the current selection against an expression and returns true,
>   if at least one element of the selection fits the given expression.
>
> If no element fits, or the expression is not valid, then the response
>   will be 'false'.

So you can be sure the answer will either be `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you use `console.log()` or any way you like to check the values, but I've made an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4vu8c/1/).

The value will be `true` or `false`